# swiftUI: strange behavior with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: swiftui, avaudioplayer

I want to build an Onboarding Screen for an app especially for blind people. so the pages should play a small mp3 file.

But if I implement the code as attached, the behavior seems weird for me.
If I change from page 1 to page 2 the first mp3 file stops and the second starts. as I want it.
if I go further to page 3 the mp3 from page 2 continues and the mp3 from page 3 starts also. the both sound are overlaying each other.

I don't understand why .onDisappear sometimes seems not to be executed...

*sometime Xcode throws a
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
--> solved by the hint from jnpdx - Thanks*

in the .onDisappear section.

Here is a litte video of my problem. Maybe it's easier to understand what I mean if you see the video...

https://www.eckeonline.de/RPReplay_Final1643832563.MP4

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ManualView: View {
    
    let titleText = ["Willkommen", "Kategorien", "Neuigkeiten","Beispiel", "star.fill","cart", "star.fill","cart", "star.fill"]
    let titleImage = ["character.book.closed.fill", "list.dash", "megaphone.fill","moon.zzz.fill", "star.fill","cart", "star.fill","cart", "star.fill"]
    let soundFile = ["WelcomePage","CategoryPage", "NewsPage", "ExamplePage","WelcomePage", "WelcomePage", "WelcomePage","WelcomePage", "WelcomePage", "WelcomePage"]
    
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            
            
            ForEach(0..<4) { value in
                OnboardingPage(soundFile: soundFile[value], title: titleText[value] , image: titleImage[value])
                    .tag(value)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}



struct OnboardingPage: View {
    
    var soundFile: String
    let title: String
    let image: String
    @State var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 25) {
            
           //  PlayMP3View(soundFile: soundFile)
            Text(title)
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .font(.system(size: 200))
                .lineLimit(1)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.25)
            //  .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .accessibility(hidden: true)
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: image)
                .font(.system(size: 200))
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .accessibility(hidden: true)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear() {

            if let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundFile, ofType: "mp3") {
                self.audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound))
                self.audioPlayer.play()
            }
        }
        .onDisappear() {
            self.audioPlayer.pause()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Any time you use `!`, you risk a crash if that value ends up `nil`. The easiest solution here is to make `audioPlayer` an optional.

Comment: Hi jnpdx, good hint. now the app don't crash anymore. But this strange behavior with overlaying sound is still there.

Comment: The tab probably isn't getting truly unloaded (and not called onDisappear). Instead of using `onAppear` and `onDisappear`, how about using `onChange` and watching the selection of the `TabView` (using `TabView(selection:)`)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand what you mean? how should I play() or pause() in a .onChange(of: selectedTab)?

Comment: if I use onChange(of: selectedTab) { newValue in
            self.audioPlayer?.pause()} it isn't working correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you use !, you risk a crash if that value ends up nil. The easiest solution here is to make audioPlayer an optional.

Second, in regards to your issue with overlapping audio, the tab probably isn't getting truly unloaded (and not called `onDisappear`). Instead of using `onAppear` and `onDisappear`, you could use `onChange` and watch the selection of the `TabView` (some of the `AudioPlayer` code is removed for brevity):

```
struct ManualView: View {
    
    let titleText = ["Willkommen", "Kategorien", "Neuigkeiten","Beispiel", "star.fill","cart", "star.fill","cart", "star.fill"]
    let titleImage = ["character.book.closed.fill", "list.dash", "megaphone.fill","moon.zzz.fill", "star.fill","cart", "star.fill","cart", "star.fill"]
    let soundFile = ["WelcomePage","CategoryPage", "NewsPage", "ExamplePage","WelcomePage", "WelcomePage", "WelcomePage","WelcomePage", "WelcomePage", "WelcomePage"]
    
    @State private var selection = -1
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            ForEach(0..<4) { value in
                OnboardingPage(soundFile: soundFile[value],
                               title: titleText[value],
                               image: titleImage[value],
                               isActive: selection == value)
                    .tag(value)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
        .onAppear {
            selection = 0 //trick to get onChange triggered on first screen
        }
    }
}

struct OnboardingPage: View {
    
    var soundFile: String
    let title: String
    let image: String
    var isActive : Bool
    
    @State var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 25) {
            Text(title)
        }
        .onChange(of: isActive) { newValue in
            if newValue {
                print("Play \(title)")
                audioPlayer?.play()
            } else {
                print("Stop \(title)")
                audioPlayer?.stop()
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. as I implementing your code, the mp3 file from the first page didn't start. changed the value from selectedTab to -1. as it's works I've seen you gave it the value -1 too :-). I've should read more detailed. But now it works. Thank You!